# How to use SUTime,NLP in python inorder to extract date

Tags: python, nlp, extract

For date extraction I tried to use NLTK (part of Natural Language Processing) - regular expression,unigram. Using these I could extract date but when I pass different messages for the same date extractor, it is unable to identify the date format. When i further googled it I came across SUTime for extracting date.

Can any one tell how to install SUTime and extract date from a text message using python?

Or

Is there any other way to extract date from a text message using python?

(NOTE: Text message are not machine generated. Hence the date format changes from message to message)

Example :
Text message : "10/10/2015 4:20 CST. At Belendoor terminal UNL is unavailable from Date: October 12, 2015 Time: 1:30 PM until 07:30pm EST."
Output :

> Date1 : 10/10/2015 04:20:00 CST
>   Date2 : 10/12/2015 13:30 
>   Date3 : 10/12/2015 19:30 EST

Comment: Maybe this might help: https://wit.ai/

Answer (score 1):

There's now a [python wrapper for SUTime](https://github.com/FraBle/python-sutime).

The following is from the README. To install:

```
pip install setuptools_scm jpype1 # install pre-reqs
pip install sutime
# use package pom.xml to install all Java dependencies via Maven into ./jars
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=./jars
```

Note: Before running the mvn dependency:copy-dependencies command, make sure you copy the pom.xml file from the above repo link to the directory where you are executing the command (This same directory must be specified in the _*file*_ path below)

Small usage case:

```
import os
import json
from sutime import SUTime

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_case = u'I need a desk for tomorrow from 2pm to 3pm'
    
    jar_files = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'jars')
    sutime = SUTime(jars=jar_files, mark_time_ranges=True)

    print(json.dumps(sutime.parse(test_case), sort_keys=True, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "end": 26,
        "start": 18,
        "text": "tomorrow",
        "type": "DATE",
        "value": "2016-10-14"
    },
    {
        "end": 42,
        "start": 27,
        "text": "from 2pm to 3pm",
        "type": "DURATION",
        "value": {
            "begin": "T14:00",
            "end": "T15:00"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

SUTime runs on the JVM. So am not sure if you can call it from Python seamlessly. There's no SUTime port for Python as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Now the python wrapper is available for the Sutime.

Please refer to the link below

https://github.com/FraBle/python-sutime

Please follow the steps:
1.pip install sutime
2.mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=./jars -f $(python3 -c 'import importlib; import pathlib; print(pathlib.Path(importlib.util.find_spec("sutime").origin).parent / "pom.xml")')

and you will get a running code !!!!!!!